# Creating a Decision Variable in Python-MIP with Dictionaries

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, python

I have already seen in the [Python-MIP](https://docs.python-mip.com/en/latest/examples.html) documentation on how to implement a variable with multiple indices. 
In each example I read, this is done with the use of **lists** and **integers** as indices.

This is how I implement a variable that I needed in the beginning:

```
x = [[[model.add_var(name='x({},{},{})'.format(e,s,a),var_type=INTEGER,ub = employeeDict[e].mitarbeiter_ist_formen)
   for e in employeeDict] for s in demandBelongingToShiftDict] for a in demandAppendedWithShiftDict]
```

But got the following error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Since the index **a** is a string.

Now I know that in Python is impossible to search within a list with strings as indices. 
This is why I would like to use **dictionaries**:

```
x = {{{model.add_var(name='x({},{},{})'.format(e,s,a),var_type=INTEGER,ub = employeeDict[e].mitarbeiter_ist_formen)
   for e in employeeDict} for s in demandBelongingToShiftDict} for a in demandAppendedWithShiftDict}
```

Unfortunately, I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haven't used python-mip but to create multi-index variables I usually do:

```py
x = {
    (e, s, a): model.add_var(
        name="x({},{},{})".format(e, s, a),
        var_type=INTEGER,
        ub=employeeDict[e].mitarbeiter_ist_formen,
    )
    for e in employeeDict
    for s in demandBelongingToShiftDict
    for a in demandAppendedWithShiftDict
}
```

and access it by `x[e, s, a]`.

You are doing `set` instead of `dict` comprehensions because you are not creating key-value pairs.

Comment: This is great. I implemented your idea and now I am not getting any errors. I will test it further and report back. The only thing I do not understand in your code is, that you only use the braces {} once. I thought I would have to do this 3 times.

Comment: I am only creating a single dictionary where the key is a `(e, s, a)` tuple and the value is the corresponding variable, I guess you could also nest multiples dictionaries (like the example with lists) but I don't think that is a good (readable) option.